# Too many categories to pivot_table in python

Tags: python, pivot-table

I would like to reshape the following table, recording the medications taken by each patient at each admission.

| Admission ID | Pills | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001-001 | M1 | 0.13 |
| P001-001 | M2 | 0.43 |
| P001-001 | M3 | 0.73 |
| P002-001 | M1 | 0.13 |
| P002-001 | M2 | 0.43 |
| P002-001 | M3 | 0.73 |

I would like to reshape the table as follow:

| Pills | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Admission ID |  |  |  |
| P001-001 | 0.13 | 0.43 | 0.73 |
| P002-001 | 0.13 | 0.43 | 0.73 |

So, I used the following code to reshape the table.

```py
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    data=df,
    index='Admission ID',
    columns='Pills',
    values='Amount',
    aggfunc='mean',
    sort=True
)
```

However, Since my table is too large, which consists of 8k categories of pills and more than 1 billion of rows, I am not able to execute the above code to reshape the df due to running out of memory. I would like to ask if there are any other ways to reshape my table? Thank you.

Comment: Likely not, the limitation is not necessarily the calculation but the memory needed to store the output. Why do you need a reshaped table? With that many values you won't be able to read it anyway, why don't you aggregate as long format?

Comment: Because I have to reshape the table to merge with other tables. Then to perform machine learning training. @mozway